# selecting a list from a object in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an object that contains a list as on of its fields, the object is mapped to the db.
I am trying to create a query that will select a few fields from the object and the fore mentioned list.

The object mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="buys")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="buy_id")
public class Buy extends DomainObject implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "buy_name")
        private String buyName;

        @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
        @JoinColumn(name="buy_id", referencedColumnName = "buy_id")
        private List<InsersionOrder> insertionOrders;

      //other fields omitted

}
```

The query I am using:

```
"select new com.dtos.domainObjects.BuyDTO(b.id, b.buyName, b.insertionOrders) from Buy b where b.buyGroupId = :groupId and b.isDeleted = false"
```

When running this query hibernate (my JPA vendor) generates a faulty query:

```
Hibernate: select buy0_.buy_id as col_0_0_, buy0_.buy_name as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_ from buys buy0_ inner join domain_objects buy0_1_ on buy0_.buy_id=buy0_1_.id inner join insertion_orders insertiono1_ on buy0_.buy_id=insertiono1_.buy_id inner join domain_objects insertiono1_1_ on insertiono1_.io_id=insertiono1_1_.id where buy0_.buy_group_id=? and buy0_1_.is_deleted=0
```

The InsertionOrder field also inherits from DomainObject.

If I omit the list and only select "simple" fields from the Buy object(i.e. id,name) the query works fine.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax creates a BuyDTO instance from each of the rows of the resultset. Even if it worked, it would not return what you want to return. A collection field may not be part of a select clause of a HQL query.

First solution: Don't return a DTO, return the entity itself.

Second solution: Select the entities, and build the DTO instances yourself:

```
select b from Buy b 
left join fetch b.insertionOrders i
where b.buyGroupId = :groupId and b.isDeleted = false

for (Buy b : list) {
    dtoList.add(new BuyDTO(b.getId(), b.getBuyName(), b.getInsertionOrders());
}
```

Third solution: select what you want, and assemble the DTOs yourself:

```
select b.id, b.buyName, i 
from Buy b 
left join b.insertionOrders i
where b.buyGroupId = :groupId and b.isDeleted = false
```

In each row of the result, you will find one ID, one buyName, and one insertionOrder. You'll thus have to create one DTO the first time you meet a new ID, and add the order to an already constructed DTO thenext times you meet this ID.

Comment: why a collection cannot be part of the select clause? I see that in your 3rd example you select the collection

Comment: Because it wouldn't make much sense, and Hibernate would know which rows of the resultset should be grouped together as part of the same list. I haven't found any reference for HQL, but the JPA2 spec says, at page 160: *"Note that the SELECT clause must be specified to return only single-valued expressions. The query
below is therefore not valid:
SELECT o.lineItems FROM Order AS o"*

Comment: >`Hibernate would know which rows of the resultset should be grouped together as part of the same list.` - I'm not so sure. If Hibernate was smart enough to join in the ID of each entity, it should know how to group the entire resultset into separate lists. After all, this is what the manual code is doing too.